# Shortening the code I use for a DIV

Tags: html, css

I use a lot of DIVs for padding and filling on my page. For example:

```
<div id="pd1"></div>
<div id="pd2"></div>  
<div id="pd3"></div>
<div id="pd4"></div>
<div id="pd5"></div>
<div id="pd6" />
```

Can you tell me is the syntax I use for pd6 valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not valid HTML. According to the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-DIV) a `<div>` tag cannot be self closing:

> Start tag: required, End tag: required

Comment: But the <div> tag in OP is ends with / char and it is a valid (<div id="pd6" />)

Comment: @adatapost, yes, that's why it is invalid => it is missing a closing tag. Div tags cannot be self-closing.

Comment: Thanks @Darin Dimitrov. The <div> is non-void HTML element.